# Ensure that a scala parent class has a formatter associated with it

Tags: scala

I have a simple type hierarchy like the following:

```
  sealed abstract class Config
  object Config {
    case class Valid(name: String, traits: List[String]) extends Config
    case class Invalid(error: String) extends Config
  }
  implicit val validFormat = jsonFormatFor(Config.Valid)
  implicit val invalidFormat = jsonFormatFor(Config.Invalid)
```

I also have client code that does the following:

```
newHttpServer().addHandler("/config", extractConfig)
```

The `extractConfig` method performs some computations and returns either a `Config.Valid` or a `Config.Invalid`, which the server will automatically convert to json by using the implicit json format objects. My problem is that there is a compiler error because `extractConfig` returns a `Config`:

```
type mismatch; found : Config 
     required: spray.httpx.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable
```

If I change the return type of `extractConfig` to `Config.Valid` then the server code compiles because `jsonFormatFor(...)` supplies the necessary automatic type conversion to make the respose a `ToResponseMarshaller` (though I admit I don't fully understand this automatic conversion as well, being somewhat new to scala). Is there a simple way to solve this by declaring that any subclass of `Config` must be a `ToResponseMarshaller`, given that `ToResponseMarshaller` is a trait that seems to be supplied via implicit conversions?

Comment: You should say which JSON library you're using. LiftJSON, e.g., allows you to give hint about abstract types to be deserialized / unmarshalled. Check here for how that works… http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525875/polymorphic-lift-json-deserialization-in-a-composed-class

Comment: I'm using spray/spray-json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have Config.Valid and Config.Invalid it should be sufficient that extractConfig returns an Either[Config.Valid, Config.Invalid]. Then your formats above should work.

Another possibility is to write your own jsonwriter (see this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/spray-user/hierarchies/spray-user/nhtnunTNMak/Yjo6NXb9lpAJ) from the mailing list).